# The "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled" doesn't work on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-chrome, noscript

I wanted to do the same on my site and noticed that it doesn't work on Chrome, and it looks like for Stack Overflow either.

Comment: What exactly did you want to do?

Comment: on SO when you disable javascript in your browser you get an message on the top, saying that the site works best with js enabled, but on google chrome it doesnt

Comment: found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787177/noscript-stuff-noscript-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome/2787224#2787224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough this seems to be a "feature" of Chrome, as Omu pointed out

[<noscript> stuff </noscript> doesn't work on google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787177/noscript-stuff-noscript-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome)

edit: Fixed in Chrome 5.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, webkit fixing that like [this](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/56064#file1) :-)

```
if (m_parentFrame->script()->canExecuteScripts(NotAboutToExecuteScript))
```

to

```
if (!m_parentFrame->script()->canExecuteScripts(NotAboutToExecuteScript))
```